# Error trying to implement EnumConverter in JOOQ with Maven

Tags: java, maven, enums, type-conversion, jooq

I haven't been able to find a full example therefore I assume I'm missing a part somewhere. I'm getting a mapping error message, specifically "An error occured when mapping record to class ...".

My `enum`:

```
public enum CustomType {
    CustomType(1, "some text"),
    CustomType(2, "another");

    private int id;
    private String value;

    private CustomType(int id, String value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

My EnumConverter:

```
public class CustomTypeConverter extends EnumConverter<Integer, CustomType>
{
    public CustomTypeConverter() {
        super(Integer.class, CustomType.class);
    }
}
```

My `POJO` is:

```
public class MyPojo {
    private CustomType customType;

    public MyPojo(CustomType customType) {
        this.customType = customType;
    }

    // setter/getter
}
```

From what I understand the converter link can be done in a config file, in maven, and programatically. I would prefer to do it in maven.

My `pom.xml`

```
...
<plugins>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
       <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
        <executions>
           <execution>
               <phase>generate-sources</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>generate</goal>
               </goals>
           </execution>
       </executions>
        <configuration>
           <jdbc>
               <url>${db.url}</url>
               <user>${db.username}</user>
           </jdbc>
            <generator>
                <database>
                    <includes>.*</includes>
                    <inputSchema>mySchema</inputSchema>
                    <customTypes>
                        <customType>
                            <name>com.myPackage.enum.CustomType</name>
                            <converter>com.myPackage.converters.CustomTypeConverter</converter>
                        </customType>
                    </customTypes>
                    <forcedTypes>
                        <forcedType>
                            <name>com.myPackage.data.MyPojo</name>
                            <expression>.*\custom_type</expression>
                            <types>.*</types>
                        </forcedType>
                    </forcedTypes>
                </database>
                <target>
                  <packageName>com.myPackage</packageName>
                  <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
                </target>
            </generator>
       </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
...
```

And in case this helps the database changelog for the database column is:

```
<column name="custom_type" type="INT">
```

And the select code is:

```
public List<MyPojo> getPojos(long id) {
    return dslContext
            .selectFrom(MY_POJO)
            .where(MY_POJO.ID.eq(id))
            .fetchInto(MyPojo.class);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible problems here:

#### Your enum converter is not correct

jOOQ's built in [`EnumConverter`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/EnumConverter.html) can only convert between "ordinals" <-> enum or "names" <-> enum, ordinaly correspond to [`Enum::ordinal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()) and names correspond to [`Enum::name`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#name()). In your example, you've added something like a "label" to your enum:

```java
CustomTypeA(1, "some text"),
CustomTypeB(2, "another");
```

I'm assuming your actual enums are not both named `CustomType`, that's not possible in Java, so I've added `A` and `B` suffixes. With these enums, jOOQ's [`EnumConverter`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/EnumConverter.html) can now map `0 <-> CustomTypeA` and `1 <-> CustomTypeB`, or `'CustomTypeA' <-> CustomTypeA` and `'CustomTypeB' <-> CustomTypeB`

I guess you would have liked for jOOQ to map your database values to your `id` or `value` string, but there really isn't any automatic way for jOOQ to discover that this is what you may have meant.

#### Your code generator config is incorrect

Your `MyPojo` class is not the one you want to be applied to your particular column(s), it is a wrapper type that you're using to wrap *records*, not individual *values*.

What you probably wanted to configure is this:

```xml
<forcedType>
    <userType>com.myPackage.enums.CustomType</userType>
    <converter>com.myPackage.converters.CustomTypeConverter</converter>
    <expression>.*\custom_type</expression>
    <types>.*</types>
</forcedType>
```

#### You're selecting all columns, and try to map them onto a POJO

Finally, your POJO doesn't have a default constructor and is thus treated by jOOQ as an immutable POJO. This means that jOOQ will map the columns in their order of projection (your `SELECT` clause) onto the constructor arguments. Your constructor only has one parameter, but you're selecting all columns from your table. Quite possibly, there's also a mismatch between source and target columns.